# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (2) simple solution

Tags: python, numpy

I have this np array and trying to add a number to one of just one of lines(trying to make asymmetric array if possible and if not a 100*3 array is also ok)

```
a=np.arange(100*2).reshape(-1,2)
a[40]=np.append(a[40],6)
```

note that `a=np.arange(100*2).reshape(-1,2)` is just simplified example and not real code that I wanna manipulate.
and I receive this error

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (2)
```

is there any simple solution(except making new array and filling it with loop with previous value then adding 6)?

Comment: Are you trying to add `6` to the row `a[40]` ? or What should `a[40]` look like after the operation ?

Comment: yes as third column

Comment: Well, i am not sure if you can do that. Because the `array` is of shape (N, 2)

Comment: But you can do something like `a = np.append(a, np.zeros((a.shape[0], 1)), axis=1)` and then `a[40, 2] = 6` ?

Comment: yes I want `a[40, 2] = 6`

Comment: Okay, use that then.

Comment: do u know can it be done asymmetric?

Answer (score 0):

Would that be a solution to your problem?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((100, 3))
a[:,0:2] = np.arange(100*2).reshape(-1,2)

a[40,2]=6
```

Comment: thank u but `a=np.arange(100*2).reshape(-1,2)` is just simplified example and not real code that I wanna manipulate. so I wanna keep `a` and also I was more inclined to get an asymmetric answer more.

Comment: If you want an asymmetric solution, you have to use either an array of lists or a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing in `numpy` to a ragged array is an object dtype array:

```
In [475]: a = np.empty(2, object)                                                                    
In [476]: a                                                                                          
Out[476]: array([None, None], dtype=object)
```

If an element is a list, you can use its `append` to add a value:

```
In [477]: a[0] = [1,2]                                                                               
In [478]: a[1] = [2,3]                                                                               
In [479]: a[1].append(4)                                                                             
In [480]: a                                                                                          
Out[480]: array([list([1, 2]), list([2, 3, 4])], dtype=object)
```

But it's questionable whether such an array is any better that a list

```
In [481]: a.tolist()                                                                                 
Out[481]: [[1, 2], [2, 3, 4]]
```